# Can an analog to the Meissner Effect be proposed for matter and gravitational fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, superconductivity, matter

In the study of electromagnetic fields and quantum electrodynamics we observe and theorize on the behavior of [superconductivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity) and the [Meissner effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect). Has an analog of these behaviors been proposed to gravitational field theory and matter?

If so what possibilities could these propositions lead to?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2767/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19896/2451 and links therein.

Comment: You may be interested in this paper by Donato Bini regarding some work he and his colleagues conducted (http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.4596). They essentially show that lines of force can miss the black hole (Fig 4, pg 10, resmebling the Meissner effect). As for a purely gravitational case, I could not say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gravitational analogue of magnetism is called "gravitomagnetism" (and the general mathematical analogy between Maxwell's equations and gravitation in general relativity is called [gravito-electromagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism)), which deals with the gravitational interactions of currents of mass/energy, just as magnetism deals with interactions of currents of charge. According to the book *The Measurement of Gravitomagnetism: A Challenging Enterprise* by physicist [Lorenzo Lorio](http://digilander.libero.it/lorri/homepage_of_lorenzo_iorio.htm), there is no gravitomagnetic analogue of the Meissner effect: see section 4.3 on pages 45-47 which can be read on google books [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=zeinb7OfDIUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA45). Quoting just the introduction and conclusion of this section:

> If however one wants to consider a real analog of the pure Meissner
>   effect, one should treat the pure gravito-magnetic case. To be more
>   definite, we should envisage a situation where matter can flow without
>   friction in response to a gravito-electromagnetic field, i.e. matter
>   in a pure superfluid state.
>
> ...in principle, in superfluids there is no analog of the Meissner
>   effect in superconductors. In other words, recalling a remark by
>   Pascual-Sánchez [142], we can say that superfluids in gravito-magnetic
>   fields display a paramagnetic-like behavior rather than a
>   diamagnetic-like one.