# Can gravity be blocked or augmented?

Tags: gravity

If gravitons (or some other quantum particle) are indeed responsible for the effect of gravity, can gravity be blocked, defected or trapped somehow?

Is there any evidence that a gravitational field can be augmented at all, other than by another massive object?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19896/

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2767/2451 and links therein.